# How can the notation $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ be used in scientific papers?

Tags: trigonometry, notation, article-writing

During a presentation for a PhD engineering topic I had shown the $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ function within a slide as part of an equation. I received a remark by a professor that $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ is not official and that I should not use it. Then I sent him the definition of $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ as:

[image]

and he said that I should've used that one instead of $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x).$

I'd like to ask if there is a correct mathematical approach towards using this function within papers and scientific presentations so I can avoid any further remarks. Using the complete mathematical definition seems rather cumbersome, is there any simplified approach? What would be the correct approach in such situations? In the end I'd like to ask if there is any guideline book that contains the official math notation which can only be used in science papers or presentations.

Comment: I do not see a problem with using this notation in an article as long as you define it before the first usage.

Comment: @PhillDonn FYI, a question like yours may be better suited for the [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com) SE site. I've read quite a few posts there, including a fair number that deal with issues regarding scientific papers (e.g., formatting, authorship, citations, content issues, etc.), with at least a few of them being about math papers. For example, there are over $7$,$000$ posts there with the [publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications) tag. Nonetheless, if you're considering posting there, please first check for any duplicates, read their ...

Comment: @PhillDonn (cont.) [Help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help) such as what is allowed, and not allowed, to be posted there, check several possibly appropriate tags (such as the "publications" one I mentioned earlier), read at least several related posts there to get an idea of how to best phrase your question, etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "he said that I should've ***used that one*** instead of $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x).$" Don't you mean that he said that you should have supplied the definition of $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ as a preface to using it in your paper/presentation? Since you're using a non-standard function, why wouldn't you bother to define (and even introduce) it prior to using it ?

Comment: @ryang Because it was a very short 10 minute presentation that had to contain efforts that took over 1 year. Spending a slide and time on such obvious simple function would've taken a large portion of the time. But I definitely understand your remarks that I should've made a hidden slide for the mathematical definition in case someone asks. In the end, it is a very common function used in engineering and, honestly, I never really expected such question. Therefore, I am trying to improve my notation to be as simple and as comprehensive in the future.

Comment: @PhillDonn Ah, that's fair, I understand now. He has a point though: *during the presentation*, please just display the whole dang thing (no need to elaborate since it's self-explanatory and since time is short) since the audience may not recall the details of that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be fine with seeing $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ in a mathematics paper and just assume that the author prefers that notation over alternatives. But a brief explanation for readers not familiar with the notation wouldn't hurt, eg "$\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ is the polar angle of the point $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$ taking values in $(-\pi, \pi]$" or "$\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) = \arg(x + iy)$" or one of the explicit formulas. If the exact range of values (looks like $(-\pi, \pi]$ in your formula) is important then I would recommend including it explicitly in any case.

I think the general rule of thumb is that any notation that is unambiguous and explicitly defined is ok, anything else depends on the field and you should use your (or your advisor's or ...) field-specific experience and judgment. In particular a guideline of the type you suggest that tries to cover all of mathematics would not be very useful.